# Calculate total running time of pods using two date/timestamp columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, group-by

I am currently storing all the pods in Postgresql db. I track each pods creation and deletion through **created_time** and **deleted_time** column. When pod is not deleted, its **deleted_time** columns remains null.

SqlFiddle can be found here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bd5cb/8)

The schema is given below for quick reference:

```
create table pods (
  name text primary key,
  created_time timestamp without time zone,
  deleted_time timestamp without time zone default null
);

insert into pods (name, created_time)
values
('pod-1', '02-01-2020 01:00:00'),
('pod-2', '02-01-2020 02:00:00');

update pods set deleted_time = '02-01-2020 03:00:00' where name = 'pod-1';
```

The challenges while calculating the running time are as follows:

1. Handling null deleted_time column(pod is still running)
2. Clipping created_time and deleted_time to user given range(start and end time).

So I came up with following query which calculates the usage hours but its bit slow when you are dealing with million of pods in a given date range.

```
-- end_time = '2020-02-01 04:00:00'
-- start_time = '2020-02-01 02:00:00'

with model as (
  select
    name,
    case when created_time < '2020-02-01 02:00:00' then '2020-02-01 02:00:00' else created_time end as created_time,
    coalesce(
      case when deleted_time >= created_time and deleted_time <= '2020-02-01 04:00:00' then deleted_time else null end,
      '2020-02-01 04:00:00'
    ) as deleted_time,
    extract(
      epoch from(
          coalesce(
          case when deleted_time >= created_time and deleted_time <= '2020-02-01 04:00:00' then deleted_time else null end, '2020-02-01 04:00:00'
          ) - case when created_time < '2020-02-01 02:00:00' then '2020-02-01 02:00:00' else created_time end)) / 3600::float as usage_hours
  from pods
  where created_time <= '2020-02-01 04:00:00' and
        (deleted_time is null or deleted_time >= '2020-02-01 02:00:00')
)
select sum(usage_hours) from model; -- should return 3.
```

So here is my question: I would like to know if there is any efficient way to calculate this statistics ?. Or is it even possible to calculate it with the given schema ?

Answer (score 1):

The overall logic looks good to me.

You could simplify this a little with `least()`, `greatest()`, `coalesce()`, and simpler date arithmetics:

```
select 
    sum(extract(epoch from 
        least('2020-02-01 04:00:00', coalesce(deleted_time, '2020-02-01 04:00:00'))
        - greatest('2020-02-01 02:00:00', created_time)
    )) / 60.0 / 60 usage_hours 
from pods
where 
    created_time <= '2020-02-01 04:00:00' and
    (deleted_time is null or deleted_time >= '2020-02-01 02:00:00')
```

Comment: OP doesn't list it as a requirement, but to help with making the buckets stridable the upper bound of the range should most likely be exclusive - `created_time < '2020-02-01 04:00:00'` ("pod must have been created before this time").  It's not likely to affect the calculations shown here any, but would have an effect with things like `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But it is still slow. Do you think its possible to get this statistics using different query with better response time. Right now I take a snapshot of every hour, store it in a different table to get the same results. Pre calculating like this has its problems like if I make a mistake I have to recreate the whole table again. I would like to avoid that.